# Skype API for Linux (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, linux, skype

**Note:** I know the Skype API is no more, however, it still works for older versions of Skype on Windows, and the latest version of Skype on Linux.

I have a Skype bot that I made out of Python I use, and I'd like to remake it in C or C++. I want to do this for Linux, however, I can't find any libraries that work similarly to `Skype4COM.dll` for Linux.

So, my question is: 
Are there any Skype libraries or wrappers I can use in C/C++ on my Linux machine to create an application/plugin for Skype? (I assume there are, I just can't find any)

It doesn't *need* to work with audio/video, just the chat API mainly.
I have looked around, but haven't had any luck. I also can't seem to find anything on here related to this issue either, which seemed odd because I can't be the first person who wants to make a Skype plugin out of C/C++ on Linux.